# Нужно передать параметр из ссылки Thymeleaf в URL

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, thymeleaf

у меня есть веб страница, на ней есть несколько ссылок(зависит от количества данных в БД).
Мне нужно, нажав на ссылку, передать текст ссылки в параметры URL страницы, на которую я направляюсь.

К примеру, ссылка с текстом **Example**, я нажимаю на нее и попадаю на страницу **localhost.com/home/example**.

Можно ли так сделать и если да, то каким способом? Спасибо

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Если вы хотите использовать Thymeleaf для формирования ссылки, то для этого используйте [Link URLs](https://www.thymeleaf.org/doc/tutorials/3.0/usingthymeleaf.html#link-urls). Для примера, если текст линка приходит в переменной `${titleFromBackEnd}` ...

```
<a href="#" th:href="@{/home/{linkTitle}(linkTitle=${titleFromBackEnd})}" th:text="${titleFromBackEnd}">TitleReplacedByThymeleaf</a>
```

Если ва хотите формировать линк только при нажатии на сам линк, то вам нужно использовать JavaScript, потому что к этому времени Thymeleaf уже закончил формирование страницы и вы имеете дело с простым HTML.

Ваш JavaScript коде может выглядеть так ...

```
// когда страничка загрузится 
$(function() {
    // для всех кликов на все линки
    $('a').on("click", function(e) {
        // заменяем URL на значение которое в линке плюс имя линка
        e.originalEvent.currentTarget.href = $(this).attr('href') + "/" + $(this).text();
    });
});
```

Comment: Да, текст ссылки ко мне приходит в переменной ${titleFromBackEnd}, но в этой переменной лежат и другие значения, поэтому при использовании первого варианта в линк добавляются все значения, которые есть в этой переменной. Не могли бы вы подсказать как написать код на JS для того, что мне нужно?

Comment: Я конечно добавил код, но советовал бы использовать Thyimeleaf, вы же как то печатаете текст линка, используйте ту же переменную для части URL